# discrepancy in use of product rule to obtain derivative

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Equation 1 at  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.2160.pdf states:
$\frac{dx}{dt} (=x') = -\beta x(t) y(t)$

Rearranging, 
$y = -\frac{1}{\beta} x^{-1} x'$

And using the Product rule:
$y' = -\frac{1}{\beta}(-x^{-2}x' + x^{-1}x'')\\
=-\frac{1}{\beta}[\frac{x''}{x}-\frac{x'}{x^2}]$

But Equation 12 from this article states:
$y' = -\frac{1}{\beta}[\frac{x''}{x}-(\frac{x'}{x})^{2}]$

Why is the $x'$ term also squared?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you didn't apply the derivative correctly. Note that by the [power rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_rule) and [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), you get

$$\frac{d(x^{-1})}{dt} = -\left(x^{-2}\right)\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

You forgot the extra $\frac{dx}{dt} = x'$ factor in your derivation using the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule). Thus, you should have instead got

$$y' = -\frac{1}{\beta}\left(\left(-x^{-2}x'\right)x' + x^{-1}x''\right) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

This gives an extra factor $x'$, which explains why it's squared in the article's equation $12$.

Answer (score 0):

When you take the derivative of $x^{-1}$, it's $(-x^{-2})x'$.

(You said $-x^{-2}$, but you should remember the chain rule.)

You could have also used the quotient rule for the derivative of $\dfrac{x'}x$.

Comment: the derivative of $x^{-1}x'$ is $(-x^{-2}x')x'$.  Same idea

Comment: @doctorjay:  the derivative of $x^{-1}x'$ is $(-x^{-2}x')x'+x^{-1}x''$

Comment: sorry, my oversight